# Не запускается exe файл python на других компьютера

Tags: python, pyinstaller

при компиляции файла python в exe с использованием pyinstaller. этот файл не открывается на других компьютерах. на моем компе запускается нормально. при том что в коде просто выводит привет мир.

```
print('helloword')
```

На некоторых компах запускается , на остальных нет . при том что винда 7 у всех

Ошибка:

```
C:\Windows\system32>C:\xxx\xxx.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Users\admin3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py”, line 18, in <module>

File “c:\users\admin3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py”, line 623, in exec_module
File “multiprocessing\__init__.py”, line 16, in <module>
File “c:\users\admin3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py”, line 623, in exec_module
File “multiprocessing\context.py”, line 6, in <module>
File “c:\users\admin3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py”, line 623, in exec_module
File “multiprocessing\reduction.py”, line 16, in <module>
File “c:\users\admin3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py”, line 623, in exec_module
File “socket.py”, line 49, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: Параметр задан неверно.
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing
```

Comment: В одной из ошибок написано: DLL load failed while importing _socket. Программа не нашла нужные DLL. У меня такое часто в c++, на питоне никогда подобным не занимался. Почитайте инструкции по развертыванию программы

Comment: я по разному пытался преобразовать в exe . и пробовал pyinstaller -F xxx.py. И пробовал pyinstaller xxx.py . и ничего не работает

Comment: -f - тут не при чём, данный флаг собирает всё в одну папку.

Comment: это да , но проблема в том что на некоторых компах работает нормально . а на других выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить набор распространяемых библиотек Redistributable Package (x86) vcredist_x86 максимально последних версий. на комп на котором не работает.

Comment: не помогло я установил пакет vcredist_x86 + Microsoft .NET Framework  последний установил . все равно выдает данную ошибку

Comment: Странно. Мне однажды помогло. Но сейчас нет под рукой компа на котором бы не работало чтобы попорбовать. Как вариант еще можно попробовать взять все Dll файлы с каталога Python и его подкаталогов. С рабочего компа. Совсем все. И переписать в каталог с вашим exe. Если заработает удалять dll пока не найдете в какой проблема. p.s. найдете ответ, сообщите тут. буду следить.

Comment: не понял что нужно сделать ? перекинуть всю папку питон на другой комп? а где брать там  dll файлы ?

Comment: Не всю папку а только все .dll файлы из папки python и  его подкаталогов, в одну папку с вашим exe

Comment: не сработало , все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Ну уже из области идей.  Чтобы делал я. На той машине где работает. Но нет питона. Поставил бы питон и пересобрал бы exe. С такими замечаниями. 1. Ставить питон с Pyton.org а не с microsoft store. 2. Установить питон в короткий путь например C:\Python.   Мне однажды пришлось удалять питон установленный с msstore и ставить в короткий пусть. Иначе не ставились библиотеки. И вообще были непонятные глюки.

Comment: пересобирал . на той машине где работает , но нет питона.я установил питон и сделать exe файл . на третей  машине все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Посмотрите эту статью https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/issues/250 возможно  тут есть решение. Для питона видимо нужны какие то апдейты для windows 7.  Рекомендуют поставить KB2533625 KB2533623 обновление.

Comment: я думаю не хватает каких то dll пакетов , но как определить не понятно

Comment: да надо было обновление поставить . все заработало . спасибо

Comment: не забываем отмечать хорошие ответы :)

Comment: как отмечать хорошие ответы?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо поставить апдейт для Windows. Поставил KB2533625 все заработало . В [этой стетье](http://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/issues/250) есть решение